# C# - How to bind a single ListView with multiple DataSource from Sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, listview, data-binding, datasource, sitefinity

I believe this question was asked before several times but I couldn't get it working in my case.

I am trying to pull 2 data sources from Sitefinity through their API and want to publish it in only 1 LisView so I can easily apply pagination and sort all the data Alphabetically.

I will take care of the pagination and Sort but I just need a help in regards to binding a single ListView with 2 Data Sources.

Offcourse my code below will not work as it is just working with 1 data source I am just writing it down so you can understand the situation in a more clearer way.

Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:

## ASP.NET

```
<telerik:RadListView ID="ContentSlider1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="text-align: center">
            <h2><%# Eval("Name")  %></h2>
            <h4><%# Eval("Position")%></h4>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListView>
```

## Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Data Source 1
        var dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
        Type showcaseType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Module1.Source1");
        var showcases = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(showcaseType).Where(s => s.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live);

        // Data Source 2
        var dynamicModuleManager2 = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager();
        Type showcaseType2 = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Module2.Source2");
        var showcases2 = dynamicModuleManager2.GetDataItems(showcaseType2).Where(s => s.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live);


        ContentSlider1.DataSource = showcases + showcases2;
        ContentSlider1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: So you want to populate one ContentSlider control with combined content from two different data sources?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes I exactly want that.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.union?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Union__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__

Answer (score 1):

Showcases and showcases2 are both IQueryable of DynamicContent so you should be able to do [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.union?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Union__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__)

```
ContentSlider1.DataSource = showcases.Union(showcases2);
```